# tomcat server log on console

Tags: tomcat, logging, ubuntu-16.04

When I am starting my tomcat server, I am getting these kinds of logs on my tomcat console/tomcat window, what does this mean? I don't want these logs, How should I remove it? I am using **tomcat 9 and ubuntu 16.04.**

```
 APR Statistical data ....
    Poll Statistics .........
    Polls created           : 0
    Polls destroyed         : 0
    Polls cleared           : 0
    Network Statistics ......
    Sockets created         : 0
    Sockets accepted        : 0
    Sockets closed          : 0
    Sockets cleared         : 0
    Total send calls        : 0
    Minimum send length     : 10000000
    Maximum send length     : 0
    Average send length     : -nan
    Total recv calls        : 0
    Minimum recv length     : 10000000
    Maximum recv length     : 0
    Average recv length     : -nan
    Receive timeouts        : 0
    Receive errors          : 0
    Receive resets          : 0
    Last receive error      : 0
    Total sendfile calls    : 0
    Minimum sendfile length : 10000000
    Maximum sendfile length : 0
    SSL Network Statistics ..
    Sockets created         : 0
    Sockets accepted        : 0
    Sockets closed          : 0
    Sockets cleared         : 0
APR Terminated
```

I am getting above data each time APR is terminated and folowing warning 
SEVERE 
[main] **org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version 1.1.33 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.2.6**

Comment: Looks like you've got some kind of debugging enabled. APR is used by both Tomcat and httpd (among others). Are you running only Tomcat, or also httpd?

Comment: I Have httpd but this service is not running. I am running tomcat only.

Comment: The error message you see is pretty clear about the problem and what the solution might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `libtcnative` compiled with the `TCN_DO_STATISTICS` flag set to true. The only way to remove these log lines (which always print to stderr) is to recompile your `libtcnative` library.

The good news is that the APR connector only dumps this data when APR is being shut down, so it shouldn't be doing that e.g. on every request or connection.

You must be using an APR connector on the Tomcat side. I'd recommend switching from that connector to the NIO connector (the default) anyway for a number of reasons. If `libtcnative` is available, OpenSSL will still be used for fast TLS (compared to slow JSSE-based TLS), but APR will not be used for the sockets, and these messages should disappear.

**Update 2017-05-29**

In order to switch from the APR-based connector to NIO-based connector, simply set the "protocol" in your `<Connector>` in `server.xml` to `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`. The default is to auto-switch when the `tcnative` library is present. [[reference]](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes)

Comment: how to switch from APR connector to NIO connector?

Comment: I am getting this data each time when APR is terminated. please check the updated info